# Write a program to find sum of two numbers using functions and calculate their average?

Tags: python-3.x

I understand the questions but the thing that im not sure about is the part it says "using functions". 
here is my code and wonder if its acceptable;

```
x= int(input("Enter first number:"))
y= int(input("Enter second number:"))
sum=x+y
average=sum/2
print("Sum of the given two numbers is:", sum)
print("Average of the given numbers is:", average)
```

Comment: You probably want to create function average. `def sum(x,y): x+y;` and `def average(x,y): sum(x,y)/2;` BTW, StackOverflow is not really intended to solve your school work for you, but rather a resource to aide you in discovering the solution to the problem. Also if you are using python 3.4 you can use statistics.mean and put those numbers into an array.

Comment: `int` is a function. So are `input`, and `print`. You should avoid shadowing built-in function names like `sum` though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions are reusable piece of programs. So, you should write functions such that they can be used anywhere later. Suppose you need to calculate an average rate for something, then you'll need `avg` function to just get the value of average (without printing it) and then divide it by time to get the rate. But your code will print the sum and average values unnecessarily. So, good practice is to compute the values in the function and return them instead of printing them there.
Another point, you are using variables `num1` and `a` interchangeably. There is no need to use both of them. You can directly use `a` in the input statement. Similarly, for `num2` and `b`, use `b` directly.
And, if you are using python 3.x, you can use `//` operator to get the division result as an integer (rounded down to nearest whole number).
So, the code can be modified as:

```
def sum(x,y):
    return x+y

def avg(x,y):
    return sum(x,y)//2

a= int(input("Enter first number:"))
b= int(input("Enter second number:"))

print("Sum of the given two numbers is: ", sum(a,b))
print("Average of the given numbers is: ", avg(a,b))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def total(a,b):
   result=a+b
   print(" Sum of ",a,"and"," sun of ",b,result )  
a= int(input("Enter first number:"))
b= int(input("Enter second number:"))
total(a,b)#funtion call the 2 integer
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Tr1gZer0's comment, i think i figured it out the code.

```
def sum(x,y):
    ans = x+y
    return ans

def avg(x,y):
    avge = sum(x,y)/2
    average = int(avge)
    print("Sum of the given two numbers is:", sum(x,y))
    print("Average of the given numbers is:", average)

num1 = int(input("Enter first number:"))
a = num1
num2 = int(input("Enter second number:"))
b = num2

sum(a,b)
avg(a,b)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this would be more easy

```
def add(a,b):
    return a + b

def sub(a,b):
    return a - b

def mul(a,b):
    return a * b    

def div(a,b):
    return a / b

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    a = int(input("enter your values :"))
    b = int(input("enter your value :"))   

    print(add(a,b))
    print(sub(a,b))
    print(mul(a,b))
    print(div(a,b))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=int(input("enter 1st number"))
b=int(input("enter 2nd number"))
sum=(a)+(b)
sub= (a)-(b)
mul=(a)*(b)
div=(a)/(b)
avg=sum/2
print(sum)
print(sub)
print(mul)
print(div)
print(avg)
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer or provide some sort of context?  Why does this work?

Answer (score 0):

```
print('what you want to do with this')
i=int(input('for addition press 1 and for sub press 2 for multi press 3 for div press 4'))
print('plese enter two no')
a=int(input('enter first no'))
b=int(input('enter second no'))

def add(a,b):
    print(' sum of two no',a+b)
def sub(a,b):
    print('sub of two no',a-b)
def mul(a,b):
    print('mul fo two no',a*b)
def div(a,b):
    print('div of two no',a/b)

if i==1:
    add(a,b)

if i==2:
    sub(a,b)

if i==3:
    mul(a,b)

if i==4:
    div(a,b)
```

Comment: consider adding explanation